# Php, cUrl, cant download while I can from another server

Tags: php, curl

little piece of code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://image.example.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$c = curl_exec($ch);
```

this works from a server but wont work from another. `curl_errno()` returns false with error 7 - couldn't connect to host, and `curl_error()` say "failed to connect to %%%%%% port 80: connection timeout". **But it only applies to a specific server!** If I put an other image from google, **it does work from both server**! What can it be?

Comment: can you extend the time out value ?

Comment: @PratikSoni: its set to 60 but it runs in 1 second

Comment: Make sure the remote server is not blacklisting any of your servers. Sometimes if you're on shared hosting someone else may have caused an IP range to be blocked.

Comment: Of course, Its connection problem between server and host. Because i got same error when i added wrong url

`Failed to connect to 192.168.39.11 port 80: Connection timed out`